# Using custom data atribute for rating in RateYo

Tags: jquery, html, rateyo

I have few posts which are loaded from database and in template I set every item to have this structure:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    Rating: 
    <div class="movie_rating" data-rating="<%= movie.rating %>"></div>
</li>
```

However, I can't manage to get value from `data-rating` attribute and put it in every element:

```
$(".movie_rating").rateYo(
    {
        rating: $(this).attr("data-rating"),
        fullStar: true,
        readOnly: true
    }
);
```

I want to set rateYo to different value for every element, but when I set it on one, it's configured for all elements of certain class (for example, if rating is 1 for first element, it will be 1 for all elements).

Comment: Please can you clarify your question, @Nikola - the second part of your question appears to contradict the first part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved - I used `.each()` instead of `.rateYo()` for all elements.

```
$(".movie_rating").each( function() {
    var rating = $(this).attr("data-rating");
    $(this).rateYo(
        {
            rating: rating,
            fullStar: true,
            readOnly: true
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is included in the v2.3.2 of the plugin , you can specify the above options by doing

```
    <div class="movie_rating"
         data-rateyo-rating="<%= movie.rating %>"
         data-rateyo-full-star="true"
         data-rateyo-read-only="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `data` method:

```
$('.movie_rating').each(function () {
    var rating = $(this).data('rating');
    $(this).rateYo({rating: rating});
});
```